# NextJS API Routes Callback

Tags: api, next.js

In my application I want to offer users to connect their Google account in order to receive data from the Google Business API.

I pass the API Route as a redirect URL, as I want to catch the code passed and write the token to the database.

Unfortunately when redirecting to the redirect URL and rendering this API Route returns in ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
How can I correctly work with the API Routes to not render them in the UI, but use them to perform the action.

Comment: Code? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I was redirecting to https://localhost:XXXX
Unfortunately there is no https on localhost and hence http://localhost has to be used